# Grep differences between two lists

Tags: windows, bash, macos, grep, cygwin

I've been using a simple grep command to output differences between two files and it works fine in Windows 10 (cygwin grep), and in Windows 10's Ubuntu based Bash shell, worked great with Cygwin's Grep, but is not working on Mac OS X Yosemite.

Here is the is the very simple command line I've been using:

```
 grep -F -v -f list1.txt list2.txt > differences1.txt
```

With Mac OS X issuing that command from terminal causes a long pause and no output to screen.  I've checked both list1.txt and list2.txt to ensure they have the appropriate line terminations for their respective OS and still doesn't work.  I've consulted the man page for grep along with command line help and can't discern any difference in parameters between the different OSes that would cause this problem.  But for the record here is the Windows 10 Bash Shell Grep version (GNU grep 2.16) and Mac OS X Yosemite (BSD grep 2.5.1-FreeBSD).

Comment: What line terminations are appropriate on OSX? And do you have an empty line in `list1.txt`?

Comment: The command works as expected for me, on Yosemite.  Demo: http://pastebin.com/eiPJmqBc -- voting to close as unreproducible.

Comment: It definitely isn't working for me.  Here is a screencap [link](http://tinypic.com/r/2mx2zi8/9)

Comment: How about `\grep -F -v -f list1.txt list2.txt > differences1.txt`?

Comment: So? Did it work the same with backslash in the front? What about the full path to grep?

Comment: I resolved the issue by installing gnu coreutils and using ggrep command instead.  I didn't try using \grep command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are running the correct `grep` (not alias, function, or some script that happened to be found earlier on your `PATH`):

```
/usr/bin/grep -F -v -f list1.txt list2.txt > differences1.txt
```

---

A number of tools in FreeBSD (on which Mac OS X is based) and GNU distributions differ in functionality. That said, the parameters in your command indeed look consistent across the versions.

You can install GNU grep with Homebrew:

```
brew tap homebrew/dupes; brew install grep
```

and then run it using the command `ggrep`.

---

As a side-note: you can also install other GNU tools which also differ (like `gdate` for `date`) with:

```
brew install coreutils
```

Answer (score 2):

[`techraf`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2947502/techraf)'s suggestion to install `GNU coreutils` to use `grep` as you used in Windows Bash Shell will work for you always.

Even without that FreeBSD [`awk`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=awk&sektion=1) has enough functionality to get the difference between two files with the logic below:-

```
awk 'NR == FNR{a[$0]++; next} !($0 in a)' file1 file2
```

will do the diff between two files as confirmed on `awk version 20091126 (FreeBSD)`

Assuming my files are like below:-

file1:-

```
1
2
3
4
```

file2:-

```
2
5
```

To get the lines that are unique in `file1`, do

```
awk 'NR == FNR{a[$0]++; next} !($0 in a)' file2 file1
```

will produce output as

```
1
3
4
```

To get the lines that are unique in `file2`, do

```
awk 'NR == FNR{a[$0]++; next} !($0 in a)' file1 file2
```

will produce output as

```
5
```